# Censor Words from a File Using a CensorFile - Python

Tags: python, filter

I'm trying to create a 'censor' program which reads in a 'censorlist' with words to censor out of a 'censorfile'. I feel like I'm close, but when I run the program it's only censoring one line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os

censorlist = raw_input("File with words to censor? ")
if os.path.isfile(censorlist):
  print "The file", censorlist, "exists!"
else:
  print "The file", censorlist, "doesn't exist!"
  sys.exit()
  print ""

filterword = {}
for currentline in censorlist:
  line = currentline.strip()
  filterword.append(line)

censorfile = raw_input("File to censor using provided list? ")
script = []
for currentline in censorfile:
  line = currentline.strip()
  script.append(line)

for lines in script:
  results = []
  words = lines.split()
  for word in words:
    if word in filter:
      results.append("****")
    else:
      results.append(word)

resultfile = open(censorfile, 'w')
for items in results:
    resultfile.write(items)
```

Comment: You don't need to post the entire program, just what you're struggling with. The explanation is not clear, and the code is buggy. You assign a string to `censorlist`, then iterate over it with `for currentline in censorlist`, but it's not lines you're iterating over, it's characters.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace a bunch of substrings with `****`? If so, look at reading the file in as a string, then doing `for word in censorlist: inputfile.replace(word, '****')`. Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not clear. I'm trying to take the words from censorlist and every time they appear in censorfile, replace the word (in censorfile) with ****

Comment: @user3284938 shouldn't `filterword` be an Array instead of an Object? You are using append on an object.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the string's `replace` method to replace each instance of a substring...

```
'foo bar spam foo'.replace('foo', '****') # '**** bar spam ****'
```

You just need to iterate over the list of words to censor and call `replace` for each.

```
for word in censorlist:
    string.replace(word, '****')
```